# GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity, int, int)

Tags: java, android

I encountered an issue where when i run the directly on my mobile the app starts successfully but when i try it on the emulator it crashes before it starts with error:

```
 01-15 14:30:35.037 3735-3735/com.example.glen.countryinformationapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.glen.countryinformationapp, PID: 3735
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Dialog com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity, int, int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.glen.countryinformationapp.MainActivity.onConnectionFailed(MainActivity.java:216)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzm.zzo(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaal.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj.zzf(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj$zzb$1.zzvA(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaan$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaan$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am using a *Google Plus API* login which is only giving issues on the emulator:/ any thoughts?

Comment: You should add the part of your code where you use getErrorDialog(...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if google service api is available in your emulator..

```
 public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Activity activity) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
              googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, status, 1000).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

if not available then you can show a `dialog` that `the device is not supported for required Google Play Services`